# Variable number of arguments for an abstract function

Tags: scala

I have following code:

```
trait TypeLike
trait ArgLike
trait Predicate{
  def name:String

}

case class Arg(name:String)

case class Predicate1[I1<:Arg,O<:TypeLike](name:String, arg1:I1, output:O, func: I1=> O) extends Predicate


case class Predicate2[I1<:Arg,I2<:Arg,O<:TypeLike](name:String, arg1:I1,arg2:I2, output:O, func: (I1,I2)=> O)
  extends Predicate
```

How can I put **"func"** in Predicate trait. I don't know how to define an abstract function with variable numbers of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll have to use HLists for that. Here is an example with Shapeless HLists:

```
import shapeless._

trait Predicate[Args <: HList, O <: TypeLike] {
  implicit val lubWitness: LUBConstraint[Args, Arg]
  def name: String
  def func: Args => O
}

case class Predicate1[I1 <: Arg, O <: TypeLike](
    name: String,
    arg1: I1,
    output: O,
    func: I1 :: HNil => O
) extends Predicate[I1 :: HNil, O] {
    implicit val lubWitness = implicitly[LUBConstraint[I1 :: HNil, Arg]]
}

case class Predicate2[I1 <: Arg, I2 <: Arg, O <: TypeLike](
    name: String,
    arg1: I1,
    arg2: I2,
    output: O,
    func: I1 :: I2 :: HNil => O
) extends Predicate[I1 :: I2 :: HNil, O] {
    implicit val lubWitness = implicitly[LUBConstraint[I1 :: I2 :: HNil, Arg]]
}

// Example instantiation
val p1 = Predicate1("Example", Arg("test"), new TypeLike {},
  (args: Arg :: HNil) => { println(args(0)); ??? })
```

**Explanation**

So what happens here? An HList is basically a tuple on stereoids. Let's look at the example we have:

```
trait Predicate[Args <: HList, O <: TypeLike] {
```

`Args <: HList` means `Args` is a list of types. `O <: TypeLike` is a normal type parameter with a bound.

```
implicit val lubWitness: LUBConstraint[Args, Arg]
```

This says that we need a proof that every type in the HList `Args` is a subtype of `Arg` (I was assuming this is a requriement.

```
def func: Args => O
```

A function that takes a HList of "shape" `Args` and returns a `O`. (You can also write this as a method if you prefer.

```
case class Predicate1 /*snip*/ extends Preciate[I1 :: HNil, O]
```

`Predicate1` is a `Predicate` whose argument list contains one element of type `I1`.

```
implicit val lubWitness = implicitly[LUBConstraint[I1 :: HNil, Arg]]
```

Retrieve and define a witness that `I1` is a subtype of `Arg` (which is the case, due to the type bound in the declaration of `Predicate1`.

Comment: would you please provide an instantiation of Predicate1? I can't give arguments as Hlist

Comment: I have added an example instantiation. You might want to consider getting rid of the whole Predicate1,2,3 etc. thingy alltogether and just use HLists in Predicate.

Comment: thanks! very nice implementation, I would never learn shapeless, I have used it many times but never actually understand it to use it again!

Answer (score -2):

Tuples as type parameters could simulate something similar to your question. This approach have 2 limitations. You should use extra parens on func call and tuple have limitation on 22 item count.

```
trait TypeLike
trait ArgLike
trait Predicate[X, O] {

  def name:String

  def func(f: X): O
}

case class Arg(name:String)

case class Predicate1[I1<:Arg,O<:TypeLike, X <: Tuple1[I1]](name:String, arg1:I1, output:O) extends Predicate[X, O] {
  override def func(f: X): O = ???
}


case class Predicate2[I1<:Arg,I2<:Arg,O<:TypeLike, X <: Tuple2[I1, I2]](name:String, arg1:I1,arg2:I2, output:O)
  extends Predicate[X, O] {
  override def func(f: X): O = ???
}
```

Comment: I want it for "func" and the types should be specified!

Comment: I don't know how many args could be in trait, so I cannot say l1*,l2* because it could be like Predicate1 which only has one type

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking at all.